# Node website returns “Cannot GET/withTxt” when hosted with xxx.js

Tags: node.js

This is my code:

```
 xxx = require('./routes/xxx');

app.get('/myNodePage',routes.eXxxTxt);

app.post('/myNodePage', function(req,res,nextResult){
   xxx.emailHtml(req,res,nextResult);
});
```

And when i run this i get "Cannot GET / my Node Page". 
What am i doing wrong?
why i am getting this?

Comment: What is in routes.eXxxTxt

Comment: exports.eXxxTxt = function (req, res) {
res.render('myNodePage', { title: 'myNodePage' });